# Change only the Public URL of an Alternate Access Mapping via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, alternate-access-mapping

this must be possible via PowerShell as it can be done from Central Administration. I have a task to modify just the public URL of an existing alternate access mapping (AAM).

```
PS U:\> $aam = Get-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication http://mysite
PS U:\> $aam

IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://default.mysite   Default         http://default.mysite
http://mysite           Internet        http://mysite
```

So with the above AAM, in the Internet zone, I need to change the public URL to say `http://othermysite`

If I run

```
PS U:\> Set-SPAlternateURL -Identity http://mysite -Zone Internet -Url http://othermysite
```

I end up with both the public URL and Internal URL changed

```
PS U:\> $aam = Get-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication http://othermysite
PS U:\> $aam

IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://default.mysite   Default         http://default.mysite
http://othermysite      Internet        http://othermysite
```

As well, Set-SPAlternateURL does not provide an argument -Internal like the New-SPAlternateURL cmdlet.

If I run

```
PS U:\> New-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication http://default.mysite -Zone Internet -Url http://mysite -Internal
```

I get the correct aam, but I have two in the list of Internet zone aam now.

```
PS U:\> $aam = Get-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication http://default.mysite
PS U:\> $aam

IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://default.mysite   Default         http://default.mysite
http://othermysite      Internet        http://othermysite
http://mysite       Internet        http://othermysite
```

If I try to remove the aam

```
http://othermysite      Internet        http://othermysite
```

both aam for the Internet zone are removed.

So how can I get the following accomplished via PowerShell, or is this only possible via the GUI in Central Administration?

```
IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://default.mysite   Default         http://default.mysite
http://mysite       Internet        http://othermysite
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in three steps as the IncomingURL and PublicURL are equal. Start by removing what you have on the internet zone (1) and build your url-structure starting with the PublicURL (2). When that's done - set a new URL for the IncomingURL (3).

```
#(1)
Remove-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication http://mysite -Zone "Internet"

#(2)
New-SPAlternateURL http://othermysite -Zone "Internet"

#(3)
New-SPAlternateURL http://mysite -Zone "Internet" -internal
```

Now you have what you wish for:

```
IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://mysite           Internet        http://othermysite
```

From this setting, you are able to set the publicURL since it differs from the IncomingURL:

```
Get-SPAlternateURL “http://othermysite” | Set-SPAlternateURL “http://newothermysite”
```

And the outcome will be

```
IncomingUrl             Zone            PublicUrl
-----------             ----            ---------
http://mysite           Internet        http://newothermysite
```

Reference: [Remove-SPAlternateUrl](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607587.aspx), [New-SPAlternateUrl](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607632.aspx) and [Managing SharePoint 2013 with PowerShell: Working with Alternate Access Mappings](http://www.petri.co.il/manage-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-2013-powershell.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally wrote "-Zone Internet" in your command. That should be the problem.

The command you need should be this:

```
PS U:\> New-SPAlternateURL -Url http://mysite -WebApplication http://default.mysite -Zone Default -Internal
```

[Here is an Link](http://books.google.de/books?id=3x8SJ66oHcYC&pg=PT75&lpg=PT75&dq=set-spwebapplication%20-zone&source=bl&ots=HmuQB2aU0k&sig=SV56oSoC_5mBEOHeWcy1zgm3rbc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ZxZMUqXFLInOtAbDsoBA&ved=0CHoQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=set-spwebapplication%20-zone&f=false) to a googlebook where you can find more information how to create AAM's(Chapter 5.7)

Comment: I think he wanted to change the Internet Zone mapping!

Comment: It wasn't an accident, that's the scenario

Comment: Sorry my fault.